# Show ads on one place one by one on refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74zny.png)

In this image you can see there are two ads but i want to its appear one ad on every page reload.. so how its possible in html and php?

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: Hi Muhammad and welcome to SO. In the current state your question is broad and very hard to answer. To be able to help you, you'll need to specify very clearly what you're trying to do, what you've already tried to make it work and include the code which is relevant to the question. The more effort you put in your question, the higher the probability of a quality answer.

Comment: Who serves your ads? With most ad services you can write the html for each page on your site to offer just one ad position to your ad service. Then they, the ad service, will choose one appropriate ad to fill the position on each page load.

Comment: <?php $splitIt = rand()&1; echo "<!-- $splitIt -->"; ?>
<?php if ($splitIt == 0) { ?>
<!-- First ad goes here -->
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($splitIt == 1) { ?>
<!-- Second ad goes here -->
<?php } ?>

Answer (score 0):

you should make ad session on php, and when another get request comes from page,
change ad order